# problems with using cURL POST method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xhtml, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website in order to extract XHTML data to save as variables in PHP.

The website uses AJAX which means the data I am seeking is returned following an XMLHttpRequest using a search string such as `http://website.com/ajax.php?mid=2&pid=4`

I have tried setting the request headers obtained from both Chrome and Firefox (which differ slightly) and included them trying both `curl_setop()` and `stream_context_create()` options with `file_get_contents()`, but the data is still not being returned. When I check the request headers of my script in Chrome it is displaying the method as `GET` even though this has been set to `POST`. It does this for both cURL and stream contexts.

The website does not require a login, but I have noticed that it sends session cookies as part of the request, which I have also included in the HTTP request to no avail.

One other point to note is that removing the `Content-Length` value from the request header returns a blank page immediately, whereas leaving it in stays loading for around one minute before timeout, but this may be irrelevant.

My questions are has anyone else had experience with PHP and AJAX requests using HTTP headers and why am I seeing a `GET` request when I have specified this as `POST`?

Thankyou in advance for any insights.

Comment: We can't really give insights without seeing the actual code you've tried.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Which site is it? Maybe can help you out by knowing that.

Comment: uk.msi.com/product/vga/

Comment: remember to use curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST,1). Also server may require the data to come as POST data and not as parameters in the URL, use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: Where does the POST occur on the site? What are you trying to view?

Comment: when you go to a specific model, for example GTX560Ti, both the model variations and their specifications make a `POST` request to `http://uk.msi.com/iajax.php`

Comment: You have to enable the cookie jar in setopt, don't send them with headers.

Comment: @anttir this, in conjunction with `curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));` solved my problem! if you would like to post as an answer I would be glad to accept. thankyou

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do POST in CURL:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( empty( $_SESSION ) ) {
  header('Location: /directar/index.php/site/login/return/Test');
}
echo "Info de sesion:";
var_dump( $_SESSION );

$c = curl_init('http://ws048-nueva/directar/index.php/AccessTest/CheckAcess');
$parametros_post = 'action=verChau';
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros_post); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
session_write_close();
$page = curl_exec ($c);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo  $page;
curl_close ($c);

if( $page === 'true' ) {
  echo "<br>si";
}
else {
  echo "<br>no";
}

?>
```

This was done by me to use CheckAccess method in Yii to return true or false if the current logged in user has permissions to do the action I send as POST parameter, and it's working. (I am passing session info cookie).